# Ruby count of the most frequent number in big integer

Tags: ruby

I have big number for example `123456782345673455676767878`

And i need to find the amount of the most frequent number in this big integer

Comment: Do you mean the most frequent _digit_?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Answer (score 2):

```
num = num.digits # turn num into an array of digits [1, 2, ...]
num.tally.max_by { |digit, count| count }[0]
```

Note: solution only works on ruby 2.7+ (when [tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) method was added)

Comment: It is of no consequence here, but after "num = num.digits # turn num into an array of digits [1, 2, ...]" The array of digits would be [..., 2, 1]